# IOS NSString replace text in between a range

Tags: ios, nsstring

Update: I forgot to mention that i have a big string of html and this src="" is a part of it. So, my question is how to find this particular "file:///.../" and remove it ?

How can I replace a NSString value

```
src="file:///var/mobile/Applications/92AE599A-1231223151B-4B3A-8C9B-950225AF5971/something.app/smiley-1.png"
```

to

```
src="smiley-1.png"
```

Comment: Could you not use `[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley-1.png"]`? then the part you don't want will not be added to the source.

Answer (score 3):

src = [src lastPathComponent];

Answer (score 0):

you can use [componentsSeparatedByString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) function of NSString

```
NSArray *array  =  [src componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
src             =  [array lastObject];
```